# How do I send a fetch request to Paypal's Oath API (v2)?

Tags: javascript, rest, curl, paypal, fetch-api

I have spent days trying to figure out the pieces to get a working payment portal on my website. I am not selling products directly from the website, but I do want to accept payments for invoices issues from my Paypal business account through my website. In order to do that, I need to be able to retrieve a list of invoices associated with their email address so they can select one and pay for it, which I can do through the [Invoiced API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/invoicing/v2/). In order to do *that* I need to make a call to the [Authentication API](https://developer.paypal.com/api/rest/authentication/) to get an access token.

The Authentication API documentation gives me instructions for making the request via `cURL` and `Postman`, neither of which I've used before. I found a site that could convert the `cURL` request into a `fetch` request, which gave me the following:

```js
fetch("https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token", {
  body: "grant_type=client_credentials",
  headers: {
    Authorization: "Basic PENMSUVOVF9JRD46PENMSUVOVF9TRUNSRVQ+",
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  },
  method: "POST"
})
```

I figured the string in the `Authorization` property was based on the original `-u "<CLIENT_ID>:<CLIENT_SECRET>"` cURL flag from the API's documentation, so I did a little further digging and figured, based on the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30203044/using-an-authorization-header-with-fetch-in-react-native) that I could change that to the `Authorization` property to `'Bearer ' + CLIENT_ID:CLIENT_SECRET`, so pulling the Client ID and Client Secret from the env variables and storing them into `clientID` and `secret` respectively (on the server side, of course), I then tries using the following code:

```js
    const token = await fetch("https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token", {
        body: "grant_type=client_credentials",
        headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${clientID}:${secret}`,
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        },
        method: "POST"
    })

    console.log(await token)
```

and it printed out the following:

```json
Response {
  size: 0,
  timeout: 0,
  [Symbol(Body internals)]: {
    body: PassThrough {
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 5,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      allowHalfOpen: true,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kCallback)]: null
    },
    disturbed: false,
    error: null
  },
  [Symbol(Response internals)]: {
    url: 'https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token',
    status: 401,
    statusText: 'Unauthorized',
    headers: Headers { [Symbol(map)]: [Object: null prototype] },
    counter: 0
  }
}
{
  name: 'AUTHENTICATION_FAILURE',
  message: 'Authentication failed due to invalid authentication credentials or a missing Authorization header.',
  links: [
    {
      href: 'https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/overview/#error',
      rel: 'information_link'
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: try Base64Encoding, Base64_Encoding(CLIENT_ID:CLIENT_SECRET), see this answer for details  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55901143/generating-oauth-authorization-token-using-base64-encoding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `axios` instead of `fetch`

You needs to encode to `Base64 format` the `Client id` and `Client Secret` part.
it help to little bit of protection instead direct text.

### base64 encoding for authorization

> base64.encode(client_id + ":" + client_secret)

> Authorization: Basic `Base64 result`

Example:

`Client id`: bHRpY3VsdHwuY29tcH

`Client Secret`: pQaE-ceDi3nFz

encode base 64(bHRpY3VsdHwuY29tcH`:`pQaE-ceDi3nFz) -> YkhScFkzVnNkSHd1WTI5dGNIOnBRYUUtY2VEaTNuRno=

`Authorization`: `Basic YkhScFkzVnNkSHd1WTI5dGNIOnBRYUUtY2VEaTNuRno=`

detail information in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74751006/error-testing-api-post-via-postman-and-curl/74752299#74752299)

### Full code - save as `get-token.js` file name

```js
const axios = require("axios")
const base64 = require('base-64');

const getToken = async () => {
    try {
        const client_id = 'Aeb...your-client-id...s-q'
        const client_secret = 'EDM...your-secret...ZXv'

        const response = await axios.post('https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token',
            new URLSearchParams({
                'grant_type': 'client_credentials'
            }),
            {
                headers:
                {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + base64.encode(client_id + ":" + client_secret)
                }
            })
        return Promise.resolve(response.data.access_token);
        // for debugging
        // return Promise.resolve(response.data);

    } catch (error) {
        return Promise.reject(error);
    }
}

getToken()
    .then(token => {
        console.log("access token: " + token)
        // for debugging
        // console.log("response: " + JSON.stringify(token, null, 4))
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error.message);
    });
```

### Install & run it

```
npm install axios base-64
node get-token.js
```

### Result

[image]

### You can verify by Postman

[image]
[image]

Detail information in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74751006/error-testing-api-post-via-postman-and-curl/74752299#74752299)

If you have a still some error, Check your `permission` & `App feature options` on [developer portal](https://developer.paypal.com/dashboard/accountStatus)

[image]

[image]
And change a debugging code - line 22~23, line 32~33
You can see the scope and other information.

[image]

Comment: This worked, it returned a data payload with the token, but it *also* returned this: `{
  name: 'AUTHENTICATION_FAILURE',
  message: 'Authentication failed due to invalid authentication credentials or a missing Authorization header.',
  links: [
    {
      href: 'https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/overview/#error',
      rel: 'information_link'
    }
  ]
}`
Do you have any clue why it the result would have that but also give me the token?

Comment: I updated my answer, I think  you may not have a full permission or check `App feature options` and how to debug by switching some lines.

Comment: I tested again the `get-token.js`. It works without error.

Comment: that's probably it - I disabled some of the features I didn't need for security. Thanks!