# TrueNAS Authentication using session token

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, bearer-token

I'm in the process of writing a series of Ansible tasks for TrueNAS-SCALE-22.12.0.  The plan was to use a session token for each playbook to authenticate.

There is an api endpoint `auth/generate_token` which will return what looks like a session token when accessed using a basic authentication (user:password).

I've used both Ansible and Postman to test a dozen or so authentication approaches using the token that is generated, and each results in `401: Unauthorized` errors.  I've even tried variations of base 64 encoding (just in case).

It is possible to use the basic authentication to generate a user api token, which then can be used as a bearer token in subsequent requests.  So my question is not so much about how to achieve my automation goal, but rather to understand what the `auth/generate_token` endpoint is for and how to use it.

Here is [some background](https://www.truenas.com/community/threads/freenas-api-v2-authenticate-with-generated-token.85417/) and here are the [docs](https://www.truenas.com/docs/api/scale_rest_api.html#api-Auth-authGenerateTokenPost).  Not really clear to me.

Edit:

Here's an example of the session token returned by the `auth/generate_token` endpoint:

`bYYJSTw8U3kZg5QxIyKgeLgPWIQtVKhu0FoGq3oSYWE7kQFCkNxeHWw7zcZbGPvH`

Comment: This Basic [token example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74779027/how-do-i-send-a-fetch-request-to-paypals-oath-api-v2/74779229#74779229).

Comment: @BenchVue - That example uses the same method as Ansibles `b64encode` and `b64decode`.  I've tried both.  The decode throes a no a `latin-1` codec error.

Comment: You need to success from postman first, it success can figure out base64 problem or other's issue. Did you success it by Postman?